# Onclick JS function call, returns "Can't find variable" only in Safari Console

Tags: javascript, safari

So I have a very simple JS function written that works like the following.

There is a button that has the following code:

```
<button type="submit" class="large button" onclick="addCart(76,95,73,96);">
    <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart
</button>
```

Now when that is clicked there is a very simple function added to the page below that looks like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addCart(pid, pattr, pval, pscent = 0) {
    ...
    }
</script>
```

This works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, Chrome for Mobile, Safari for Mobile.

But this **does not seem to work** on Safari on Mac. Instead I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: addCart

I cannot figure out why. It's hard for me to add a listener because there are 7 buttons and a wide arrange of variables that are being sent, and I'd rather send that like I'm currently doing.

Comment: do you get that error when you click the button or when the page loads?

Comment: The script tag is in the body, and it doesn't matter if it's first, or last, again works every browser except Safari. And I get this error only when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the issue.

The function was creating an error in Safari so it was never being defined. I changed the function to the following:

```
function addCart(pid, pattr, pval, pscent) {
    pscent = (typeof pscent !== 'undefined') ?  pscent : 0;
...
}
```

Notice the big difference is that I was no longer using the Function to declare a default value for 'pscent' and instead I do it the old school method. Not sure if this is being caused by an older version of Safari or what.

If you are here because of a similar error, look for some potential JS error in the function which will prevent the function from being declared.

Comment: I appreciate that other are having this issue with safari, because it drives me nuts! Especially because (1) with mobile safari on an I-phone, there is no such things as a console window to show what the hell the problem is, and (2) when a perfectly working block of code is simply moved from your test page to an existing JS file, and suddenly the function isn't there. You can spend all day stripping out pieces of code before you find the so called "culprit".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are submitting a form since the input type is "submit".  Have you tried testing it with the input type set to "button"?

Comment: I tried it but no luck. Safari seems to be trying to call it but can't find it.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using jquery try to use document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
// code here
});
```

or use plain javascript self executing function here

```
(function() {
   // your page initialization code here
   // the DOM will be available here

})();
```

the possible reason is your function is not available at the time of click

Here is a sample (using jquery) https://jsfiddle.net/baphmoLt/

Comment: I don't think you read the question. This is just a function in the javascript. This generally isn't loaded with a document ready call, and there is no page initialization code. The function is definitely loaded, I can wait for 10 minutes and still broken, the script can even be moved to the first thing on the page and no change, it's a very simple function. It's not a not available issue, it's not finding it and I don't know why.

Comment: The script *will be loaded* when the click the button

Comment: @JasonDiehl Please see the fiddle. and see what i meant. thanks.

Comment: strange, it works on mac on safari for mobile. anyway happy testing and if possible remove the negative rating to my answer. thanks.

Comment: I didn't give you a negative rating, but since it isn't related to the actual issue I guess who ever did it was justified.

Comment: posted the answer above, finally found it